# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (3^n + (-5)^n) x^{7n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

I have to find the radius of convergence of the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (3^n + (-5)^n) x^{7n}$$ I know that I will have something like $|x^7|<\frac{1}{L}$. I tried finding $R$ with $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\rvert$$ but I have trouble finding that limit.I just can't figure it out.So any ideas and solutions on finding the limit are welcomed $\ddot\smile $

Comment: Perhaps the root test makes it more obvious?

Comment: When you use the ratio test, try dividing the numerator and denominator by $5^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$. Taking the ratio $|\frac{3^{n+1} +(-5)^{n+1}}{3^n + 5^n}|$ and dividing both denominator and numerator by $5^{n+1}$ you see it converges to $5$, so you have $ |x^7| <\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the one I used is the correct definition of the interval of convergence.